# Shipping calculated by weight and calculated by price for different products in the same store

Tags: shipping

Is it possible to have shipping calculated by weight and shipping calculated by price at the same time in the same store?

For example some products will be calculated by weight and some products calculated by price during checkout.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it's not possible by default.

You can implement your own shipping logic as described [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module):

Or select some custom shipping rate extension from the magento connect.